# Questions to medical problems

Tags: contract-design

I am wondering if Ethereum can be used as a platform for medical questions and answers. I am new to Ethereum. I have not tried anything before. I am not a computer geek. How can I learn more about Etherium to achieve my goal of using it for medical purposes?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest NOT to select the technology before identifying why you need that technology.

Some great suggestions for understanding Blockchain could be found [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-great-resources-to-learn-blockchain-technologies).